# Mysql workbench not showing realtions after reverse engineering database

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL workbench 5.2.35 CE to reverse a Mysql Database and show the diagram of tables with their relationships.
I am able to get every table and its fields but the relations between them is not shown. Why is that? Is there any way it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Most often, the relations between tables are not stored in the DB. How to combine two tables is entirely up to the SQL query and because there are near endless possibilities to name your columns this is not easy to guess. Try to find some SELECT statements or use brute force to find out wich columns match.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MyISAM as the database engine, your database is not fully relational. Make your database fully relational by using InnoDB engine. Then you will be able to see the relations when you do reverse engineering. But please note that each has pros and cons of its own. Google MyISAM vs InnoDB to find out more about the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested mysql-workbench for both 5.2 and 6.0 latest version.  My database got foreign key constraints defined clearly.  My database is using mysql-native SQL. But the relationships are shown as line between tables.  I have created another test database with only two tables.  In this case the InoDb was used as engine.  The foreign key constrain clearly defined.  Still it only generate two lonely table object in the ER diagram after going through the "reverse engineering" module.

While using another commercial software, I was able to generate the 'lines' between the Entities.

My question is, is this a problem of workbench itself, or some error on my part.  My database server is the latest stable version 5.6.12.  If I can get an answer, this will be good for everyone.  You don't have to waste time trying to get an ER-diagram with this piece of software.